# Merging declaration blocks

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to find out the way to sharpen the image using CSS, and I found out [this example.](https://codepen.io/giana/pen/pPLodQ?editors=1100)

```
.sharpen {
 mix-blend-mode: hard-light;

 &,
 &::before,
 &::after {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
 }

 &::before,
 &::after {
   content: '';
   background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/iI72r3gSwWY/750') no-repeat;
 }

 &::after {
   filter: invert(1);
   opacity: 0.5;
   top: -1px; left: -1px;
 }
}
```

In CSS style sheet, there are three `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, and I merged them to one like this if it results in the same image effect:

```
.sharpen {
 mix-blend-mode: hard-light;

 &,
 &::before,
 &::after {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
   content: '';
   background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/iI72r3gSwWY/750') no-repeat;
   filter: invert(1);
   opacity: 0.5;
   top: -1px; left: -1px;
 }
```

However, it does not create the same image effect as the original one. 
my questions are

1) Why does it need three separate `:after` selectors to create the effect?

2) Is there any simpler way to achieve the same effect in CSS?

Comment: Who said you need three `::after`s?

Comment: 1) pseuso elements need a `content` property. 2) The element itself (referenced as `&`) doesn't need the properties: `content`, `background`, `filter` and `opacity`. 3) the after pseudo-element needs some properties that are used specifically for it. So the way it is originally written is the best way.

Comment: You can't really trim that much; you can only trim rules that are synonymous. The only thing you can possibly trim is the overwritten `top` in `&::after`... and you'd need more lines to achieve that anyway. The three separate afters exist because it's the simplest way to achieve the effect; they're not required, per se.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "simpler way"?

Comment: invert is only applied to the after and now you made it also on the before ... changing the CSS means changing the visual and this is what you did

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I took only one example to show how trivial is the difference between both codes

Answer (score 0):

```
.sharpen {
 mix-blend-mode: hard-light;

 &,
 &::before,
 &::after {
   /** those rules will be applied to '&' AND '&::before' AND '&::after' */
 }

 &::before,
 &::after {
   /** those rules will be applied to '&::before' AND '&::after' */
 }

 &::after {
   /** those rules will ONLY be applied to '&::after' */
 }
}
```

1) It needs 3 separate blocks because some rules need to be applied only to the ::after, while some need to be applied to the ::before and ::after only, while some need to be applied to the element, the ::after and the ::before

2) From my understanding of the problem, this is the simpliest way of achieving this particular effect. If not the simpliest, it is a really simple one.